# How can i add some properties on keras model?

Tags: python, keras, opencv

So, i'm working on my project using keras model, do some training with data image which is i can get the output classification of the image i've been trained. The result goes well. But, i want to add some image properties on keras model i've built. For, example, i want to add hsv image properties on keras using opencv, so they will train together.

```
image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

i want to add this feature after i added convolution layer. What i want is

```
from keras import layers
input_ = layers.Input(shape = [96, 96, 3])
conv2 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = "same", activation = "relu")(input_)
conv2 = layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 1)(conv2)
conv2 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3, 3))(conv2)
conv2 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(conv2)

prop = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(conv2), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

flat = layers.Flatten()(prop)
fc = layers.Dense(512, activation = "relu")(flat)
fc = layers.BatchNormalization()(fc)
fc = layers.Dropout(0.2)(fc)

output = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = "sigmoid")(fc)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = input_, outputs = output)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer= Adam(lr=LR, decay = LR / 2),
                      metrics=["accuracy"])
```

But, i got an error like this:

```
TypeError: src data type = 17 is not supported
```

is it because the output shape of conv2 is (32, 32, 32)? Can anyone give me an answer to this? I do not understand how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your image is (32,32,32). The Conv2D uses 32 convolutions filters in the original color image.

So, after the convolution it does not make to take into account the color space of your initial image. You could do your transformation before entering the model or just as the first layer.

Check the layer `Lambda` to be able to include any transformation you like in your model.